# How to bound to list property in model on Kendo UI Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bound list property in model using Kendo UI Asp.Net MVC Grid but I couldnt.

Here is my VieModel:

```
            var userList = allUsers.Select(p => new UserViewModel
        {
            UserId = p.Id,
            UserName = p.UserName,
            Name = p.Name,
            LastName = p.LastName,
            HospitalCode = p.HospitalCode,
            HospitalName = p.HospitalName,
            RelatedHospitals = userHospitals.Where(t => t.UserId == p.Id).Select(x => new Hosp { HospitalId = x.HospitalCode, HospitalName = x.HospitalName }).ToList(),
            PhoneNumber = p.PhoneNumber,
            OfficePhone = p.OfficePhone,
            Email = p.Email,
            UserRoleName = p.UserRoleName,
            City = p.CityName,
            CityTownName = p.CityTownName,
            UserTracks =context.UserTracks.Where(t=>t.UserId==p.Id).Select(x => new UserTrck { LastLoginDate = x.LastLoginDate, LocalIp = x.LocalIp, LastUsedWebBrowser = x.LastUsedWebBrowser }).ToList(),
            CreatedDate = p.CreatedDate,
            UpdatedDate = p.UpdatedDate
        });
        });
```

Here is My Grid Bound That I Try:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.LastLoginDate).ClientTemplate("#=UserTracks[0].LastLoginDate#").Filterable(false).Sortable(false).Width(220);
```

But this not help me.

How can I use list in model in Kendo UI MVC Grid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You aren't listing the error you are getting or what result you are actually getting so I will assume you are getting a View Compilation Error along the lines of

> 'UserViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'LastLoginDate' and
>   no extension method 'LastLoginDate' accepting a first argument of type
>   'UserViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

Your ViewModel does not seem to have a LastLoginDate field.

You can't bind a grid column to something that does not exist.

Either make LastLoginDate a member of your ViewModel directly or bind the column to UserTracks.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.UserTracks).ClientTemplate("#=lastLoginTemplate(UserTracks)#").Filterable(false).Sortable(false).Width(220);

<script>
    function lastLoginTemplate(UserTracks) {
        return UserTracks[0].LastLoginDate;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I need this column to be sortable and filterable. Is that possible?